# Display x,y coordinates for loaded image file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to load an image file with `matplotlib` and see the coordinates of points within it, as if it were a simple `x,y` scatter plot.

[image]

I can assume that the x axis extension is `[0, 1]`, and the y axis follows the same scaling. I can load the above image file with

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("del.png")
im.show()
```

but this uses ImageMagick (I'm on a Linux system) to display the image, and no coordinates are shown in the bottom left part of the plot window as would for a simple data plot:

[image]

Comment: have you tried using `im.getdata()` rather than `im.show()`? This will give you a sequence of pixel values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pyplot for that:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(plt.imread('del.png'))
```

Comment: Excellent! Much simpler than I thought it would be. Thank you!